# Laravel 5.2 PHPUnit assertViewHasAll() Failed

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

Hi I have this unit test

```
public function test_index_coupon(){

    $coupons = factory(App\Models\Coupon::class, 5)->create();      

    $this->visit('/admin/coupons')
    ->assertResponseOk()
    ->assertViewHasAll('coupons');
}
```

Here is my controller to list index of coupons

```
   public function index()
    {
        $coupons = Coupon::all();   
        return view('backend.admin.coupons.index', compact('coupons'));
    }
```

And I can successfully list coupons with

```
@foreach($coupons as $coupon)
.....
@endforeach
```

In my view, I check it via browser.

But when I run `phpunit` I get this error

```
1) CouponsTest::test_index_coupon
ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::assertViewHasAll() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/rentcar/tests/admin/CouponsTest.php on line 24 and defined
```

Then I try modify my test from `->assertViewHasAll('coupons');` to `->assertViewHas('coupons');` and I get different error

```
1) CouponsTest::test_index_coupon
Failed asserting that an array has the key 'coupons'.
```

Whats wrong with my test code? I just want to check if visit `admin/coupons` coupons list loaded properly. so I can make sure if `$coupons` is exists in view.

**UPDATE**

It works with `assertViewHas('coupons')` don't know why, maybe something wrong with my entire test code or maybe because `use WithoutMiddleware`

Thanks for answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->visit('/admin/coupons')
    ->assertResponseOk()
    ->assertViewHas('coupons', $coupons);
```

OR (int case you plan on adding more data to assert in `assertViewHasAll`)

```
$this->visit('/admin/coupons')
    ->assertResponseOk()
    ->assertViewHasAll(['coupons' => $coupons]);
```

Comment: change to `->assertViewHas('coupons', $coupons);` and get this error `1) CouponsTest::test_index_coupon
null does not match expected type "object".`

Comment: convert `$coupons` from collection to array: $coupons = factory(App\Models\Coupon::class, 5)->create()->toArray();

Comment: I get this `1) CouponsTest::test_index_coupon
null does not match expected type "array".
` It says null but the data is seeded with faker and loaded properly via view.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing), you can see that `assertViewHasAll` recives an array as parameter.

`->assertViewHasAll(array $bindings);`

And you are giving it a string:

`->assertViewHasAll('coupons');`

Comment: Then how to make test like I expected in my case?